# A question about the exsistence of Brownian Motion?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

i am studying Random Process and i am reading the book of Durrett.When i was studying the Brownian Motion in Chapter 8,i am interested in the construction of Brownian Motion in this book.
In my opinion,the construction in this book include 3 steps:

Step 1:Construct a random process $B_t$ on $Q_2$ by the Guassian tranformation function.

Step 2:Using Borel-Cantelli Lemma to prove the uniform continuity of $B_t$ on $Q_2\bigcap[0,T]$

Step 3:Extend the measure to the continuous function space.

Clearly,the author choose a countable dense subset of $B_t$ and use Borel-Cantelli Lemma to prove the uniform continuity of $B_t$ on $Q_2$.I wonder if we don't restrict our choice of $Q_2$ ,can we prove the uniform continuity in a weaker hypothesis?
The clear statement of my question is as follows:

Suppose $B_t,t\geq 0$ is a real-value random process,satisfy that:

(i)If $t_0<t_1<...<t_n$,then $B(t_0),B(t_1)-B(t_0),...,B(t_n)-B(t_{n-1})$ is independent.

(ii)$\forall t\geq0,\forall 0<a<\frac{1}{2},\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow t}\frac{B_s-B_t}{(s-t)^a}\overset{P}{\rightarrow}0,\forall 0<a<\frac{1}{2}$

Prove or give a counterexample to show that there is a countable dense subset $E\subset R_+$,such that:$$\forall t\in E,\lim\limits_{s\in E,s\rightarrow t}B_t-B_s=0,a.e.$$

Comment: Can you make the desired statement more precise?  In particular, it matters whether you want the "a.e." to depend on $t$.  In other words, can you exclude a different null set for different $t$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment,but i think it doesn't matter because $E$ is a countable set.So just take the union of all the null set for $t\in E$,the union of these set is also a null set cause it is countable.So i don't think it matters.

Comment: Indeed, sorry.  On another note, though, what you've written is only *continuity* on $E$, not *uniform continuity*, and it will not imply a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: I am sorry,but  what the author proved in the book is that $B_t$ is uniformly continuous on $Q_2\bigcap[0,T]$,i don't point out this,it's my fault.

Comment: Okay? But it doesn't change the fact that the statement at the end of your post will not prove that the process is uniformly continuous on $E$, and it won't get you any closer to the ultimate goal of constructing an a.s. continuous process on $\mathbb{R}_+$ or $[0,T]$ or any other interval.

Comment: Really?If i have proved that $B_t$ is continuous on $E\bigcap [0,T],\forall T\in N$,i think i can get a continuous extension on $R_+$.Could you give a counterexample or some hint?

Comment: Counterexample: $E = \mathbb{Q}$, $f = 1_{[0, \sqrt{2}]}$.  It is continuous at every point of $E$ but does not have a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You are right.In fact,i just modify the standard definition (b) in the Brownian Motion to see if i can get a Brownian Motion under a weaker hypothesis.So i have edited it,how about now?